# Saving Mutiple PDF Files from Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to save 1 report to two different locations on a network Drive. The program was running smooth until I added the second save location.  I am copying the code below.  I'm looking for an alternative way to do this task that is more efficient on the computer.  What used to take a few seconds takes almost a minute for 1 report.

' wkA.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:="xlTypePDF, From:=1, To:=2, Filename:=_ "G:Path\to\folder\" & wkA.ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Value '

' wkA.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:="xlTypePDF, From:=1, To:=1, Filename:=_ "G:Path\to\other\folder\" & wkA.ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Value '

```
I = I +1
 Loop
```

Comment: Once you save the `.PDF`, is it any quicker to instead just copy the file and move it that way?  Also, is the second save location indeed the same network folder? If so, put that location first. Does it still take seconds to save the first file (whatever is first in the code), and hangs up on the second line? Or is that network location perhaps causing the slowdown?

Comment: It's the exact same network location except the second one goes into a subfolder.    It runs - It just lags my computer so bad with the new second line of code.  I don't want to just copy and move unless I'm able to just copy Page 1 and move it......  Both the two page (line 1) and 1 page (line 2) have separate purposes.

Comment: Did you put the second path first, and see if it still takes just as long? (Is it the *location on the network* that's slowing it down, or just saving twice...is what I'm trying to see)

Comment: Hmm, I'll try that right now and let you know.  My theory is it is saving it twice and me not doing it efficiently enough.

Comment: So here is what I've done.  I timed it before editing, then swapped the drive order, then put in a local save location (Desktop) and it took 34 seconds per record.  That's a very long time when I'm dealing with thousands of records.